# Как вывести последовательность слов, но в обратном порядке?

Tags: pascal

Дана последовательность,содержащая от 1 до 30 слов,в каждом из которых от 1 до 5 строчных латинских букв;между соседними словами -запятая,за последним словом-точка. Вывести эту же последовательность слов, но в обратном порядке.

Как вывести в обрантом порядке

```
 Const m=[' ','.','!','?'];
    Var s,s1,s2:string;
        A:array[1..30] of string;
        i,k:byte;
    Function Proverka(s:string;k:byte):boolean;
    Var i:byte;
        b:boolean;
    Begin
        b:=true;
        For i:=1 to k do
         if A[i]=s then b:=false;
        Proverka:=b;
    End;
    Begin
        write('Введите предложение: ');readln(s);
        k:=0;s:=s+' ';s1:='';s2:='';
        For i:=1 to Length(s) do
         if not(s[i] in m) then s1:=s1+s[i]
          else
          Begin
            if Proverka(s1,k) then
            Begin
              s2:=s2+s1+s[i];
              inc(k);
              A[k]:=s1;
            End;
            s1:='';
          End;
        writeln(s2);
        readln;
    End.
```

Answer (score 0):

Строку сами сложите?

```
procedure Extract(const s: string; idx: Integer);
var
  i: integer;
  sub: string;
begin
  i := idx;
  while (not(s[i] in m)) and (i <= Length(s)) do
     inc(i);
  if i - idx >= 1 then begin
     sub := Copy(s, idx, i - idx);
     if i < Length(s) then
       Extract(s, i + 1);
     Writeln(sub);
  end;
end;

begin
  Extract('A black cat sat on a mat', 1);
  Readln;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const 
  Delims = [' ',',','.','!','?']; 

procedure SkipDelims(const Text: string; var Index: Integer);
begin
  while (Index > 0) and (Text[Index] in Delims) do Dec(Index);
end;

procedure WriteReverted(const Text: string);
var
  Fst, Lst: Integer; // Fst ищет разделитель, Lst - индекс последней буквы текущего слова
begin
  Lst := Length(Text);     // конец строки
  SkipDelims(Text, Lst);   // пропускаем разделители (точку и пробелы, если есть)
  Fst := Lst;            
  while Fst > 0 do         // идём в цикле от конца до начала 
  begin
    Dec(Fst);              // предыдущий символ
    if (Fst > 0) and not (Text[Fst] in Delims) then 
      Continue; // если не дошли до начала строки и не нашли разделитель, то пропускаем
    Write(Copy(Text, Fst + 1, Lst - Fst)); // выводим текущее слово
    if Fst = 0 then 
      Break;               // если это первое слово в строке, то закончили
    Write(',');            // выводим разделитель
    SkipDelims(Text, Fst); // снова пропускаем разделители
    Lst := Fst;            // продолжаем с последней буквы предыдущего слова
  end;
end;

...

WriteReverted('The quick,brown,fox jumps , over the lazy dog.');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
a : char;
str, slovo, res : string;
i , k : integer;
begin
writeln('Последовательность слов должна быть: ');
writeln('1. от 1 до 30 слов');
writeln('2. от 1 до 5 строчных латинских букв');
writeln('3. между соседними словами -запятая,за последним словом-точка');
writeln('Введите последовательность:');
str:=''; i:=0;
while (a<>'.')and(i<>30) do
begin
read(a);
str:=str+a;
i:=i+1;
end;
writeln('Исходная строка');
writeln(str);
 
res:=''; slovo:='';
for i:=1 to length(str) do
begin
if (str[i]<>',')and(str[i]<>'.')
then
slovo:=slovo+str[i]
else
begin res:=slovo+','+res; slovo:=''; end;
end;
res[length(res)]:='.';
writeln('Результат');
writeln(res);
end.
```